# How to put a frame around the grammar syntax in LaTeX

Tags: syntax, grammar

How I can put a frame around the grammar syntax in LaTeX like in `listings` that we use `frame = single`? For example, for this grammar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}
\begin{grammar}

<statement> ::= <ident> `=' <expr> 
\alt `for' <ident> `=' <expr> `to' <expr> `do' <statement> 
\alt `{' <stat-list> `}' 
\alt <empty> 

<stat-list> ::= <statement> `;' <stat-list> | <statement> 

\end{grammar}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way with `framed` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\begin{grammar}

<statement> ::= <ident> `=' <expr> 
\alt `for' <ident> `=' <expr> `to' <expr> `do' <statement> 
\alt `{' <stat-list> `}' 
\alt <empty> 

<stat-list> ::= <statement> `;' <stat-list> | <statement> 

\end{grammar}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Happy TeXing

Answer (score 3):

The very basic approach without packages: a `minipage` with a `\fbox{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{9cm}
\begin{grammar}
<statement> ::= <ident> `=' <expr> 
\alt `for' <ident> `=' <expr> `to' <expr> `do' <statement> 
\alt `{' <stat-list> `}' 
\alt <empty> 

<stat-list> ::= <statement> `;' <stat-list> | <statement> 
\end{grammar}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for this additional approach! But, the first solution with `framed` is keeping the frame within the margins, ie., no need to adjust something.

Comment: @user4712458  That requirement was not in the question, but this approach also  can adjust  automatically to the margins. Try  with  `\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}  (your code) \end{minipage}}`     `;-)`